# Installing SSL Support in Weblogic 10

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I have some troubles installing my SSL Certificate into Weblogic 10, here are my configuration steps:

- Copied the .cert and .key to the server
- Executed the following:

  []# keytool -import -keystore myKeystore -trustcacerts -alias myKeystore -file myCert.cert -storepass myStorePass -noprompt
  Certificate was added to keystore
- Executing the following:

  []# java utils.ImportPrivateKey myKeystore myStorePass myKeystore myStorePass myCert.cert myCert.key
  Imported private key myCert.key and certificate myCert.cert
  into keystore myKeystore  of type jks under alias myKeystore
- Running Weblogic

  []# ./startWebLogic.sh -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore -Dweblogic.security.SSL.nojce=true

This gives me the output:

```
 <Security> <BEA-090171> <Loading the identity certificate and private key stored under the alias myKeystore  from the JKS keystore file /Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/testDomain/myKeystore .>
<Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file /root/Oracle/Middleware/jrockit_160_05_R27.6.2-20/jre/lib/security/cacerts.>
<Could not load a jks keystore from the file /Oracle/Middleware/jrockit_160_05_R27.6.2-20/jre/lib/security/cacerts. Exception: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect>
```

Now the Password IS correct, but this doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the weblogic console, did you supply the keystore password ("myStorePass") on the Keystores Tab and the private key's password on the SSL tab?

Comment: The problem was that cacert had another password which has the standard value of "changeit".